# Fleet Calculate Route API issues [here-api] - the answered question has disappeared so I am posting this again

Tags: here-api

I am having 3 issues with the Fleet Calculate Route API:

1. The below is returning a travel time of -9 seconds for one of the legs:

Q: How is it returning a negative time?

[https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={our_api_key}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-07-21T12:30:00Z&waypoint0=stopOver,840!51.499601,-0.163649;100&waypoint1=stopOver,840!51.499073,-0.165367;100;sort&waypoint2=stopOver,840!51.49811,-0.16591;100;sort&waypoint3=stopOver,840!51.497494,-0.166813;100;sort&waypoint4=stopOver,840!51.495836,-0.168292;100;sort&waypoint5=stopOver,840!51.495834,-0.168292;100;sort&waypoint6=stopOver,840!51.4956530513581,-0.168139304229726;100;sort&waypoint7=stopOver,840!51.497974,-0.163668;100;sort&waypoint8=stopOver,840!51.496995,-0.164536;100;sort&waypoint9=stopOver,840!51.493948,-0.160271;100&waypoint10=51.493948,-0.160271;100](https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=%7Bour_api_key%7D&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-07-21T12:30:00Z&waypoint0=stopOver,840!51.499601,-0.163649;100&waypoint1=stopOver,840!51.499073,-0.165367;100;sort&waypoint2=stopOver,840!51.49811,-0.16591;100;sort&waypoint3=stopOver,840!51.497494,-0.166813;100;sort&waypoint4=stopOver,840!51.495836,-0.168292;100;sort&waypoint5=stopOver,840!51.495834,-0.168292;100;sort&waypoint6=stopOver,840!51.4956530513581,-0.168139304229726;100;sort&waypoint7=stopOver,840!51.497974,-0.163668;100;sort&waypoint8=stopOver,840!51.496995,-0.164536;100;sort&waypoint9=stopOver,840!51.493948,-0.160271;100&waypoint10=51.493948,-0.160271;100)

2. The below is the same parameters as the above except for the sorting. The legs in the above have a different travel time than the same legs in the below (the waypoints are in the same order):

Q: Why are the travel times of the same legs returning different values?

[https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={our_api_key}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-07-21T12:30:00Z&waypoint0=stopOver,840!51.499601,-0.163649;100&waypoint1=stopOver,840!51.499073,-0.165367;100&waypoint2=stopOver,840!51.49811,-0.16591;100&waypoint3=stopOver,840!51.497494,-0.166813;100&waypoint4=stopOver,840!51.495836,-0.168292;100&waypoint5=stopOver,840!51.495834,-0.168292;100&waypoint6=stopOver,840!51.4956530513581,-0.168139304229726;100&waypoint7=stopOver,840!51.497974,-0.163668;100&waypoint8=stopOver,840!51.496995,-0.164536;100&waypoint9=stopOver,840!51.493948,-0.160271;100&waypoint10=51.493948,-0.160271;100](https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=%7Bour_api_key%7D&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-07-21T12:30:00Z&waypoint0=stopOver,840!51.499601,-0.163649;100&waypoint1=stopOver,840!51.499073,-0.165367;100&waypoint2=stopOver,840!51.49811,-0.16591;100&waypoint3=stopOver,840!51.497494,-0.166813;100&waypoint4=stopOver,840!51.495836,-0.168292;100&waypoint5=stopOver,840!51.495834,-0.168292;100&waypoint6=stopOver,840!51.4956530513581,-0.168139304229726;100&waypoint7=stopOver,840!51.497974,-0.163668;100&waypoint8=stopOver,840!51.496995,-0.164536;100&waypoint9=stopOver,840!51.493948,-0.160271;100&waypoint10=51.493948,-0.160271;100)

3. In general, the total travel time of a leg is different from the summation of its corresponding maneuver travel times.

Q: Shouldn't the total leg travel time be equal to the summation of the maneuver travel times?

Answer (score 0):

*1. The below is returning a travel time of -9 seconds for one of the legs*

Answer: on currently test the negative time is not reproducible any more.

---

*2. The below is the same parameters as the above except for the sorting. The legs in the above have a different travel time than the same legs in the below (the waypoints are in the same order)*

Answer: This is correct, please use the example on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api to visualization your requests on the map just switch to Export mode and push your URL: on map you can see the green markers that show you navigable start point for each waypoint and you can see the difference between sorted an unsorted waypoints. Why are difference? because in the waypoints you use transit radius 100 and then is selected a navigable link at the edge of the radius 100 meters and then of course sorted.

Recommendation: use please in waypoint parameters without transit radius first and if some waypoint can't reach the navigable link then set some radius for this waypoint.

---

*3. In general, the total travel time of a leg is different from the summation of its corresponding maneuver travel times.*

Answer: No, on currently test this differences are not reproducible any more.